# Delete not recently run jobs from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

In part of our testing setup we are build our artifacts needed and then copying a template job and settings its name so it recognizable.

> Build artifact -> copy test template -> ending with a job for each
>   test case

that means i'm ending up with lots of jobs with `Test_Client${BRANCHNAME}_Server${BRANCHNAME}`

I'm running through these jobs alot while testing that branch, but as soon as it's merged it's not going to be touched again, which is why i would like to create a job of sorts that simply deletes the jobs that havn't been run for the 14 days or so.

Does anyone know a way of doing this? and not just cleaning out the workspace.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be a big change, but this is an ideal case for the Multibranch pipeline.

On one project, we have a master branch and version branches. The developers branch to short-lived feature branches or other branching purposes. As the branches are created and pushed to github, the multibranch job picks them up and starts building them. Developers get quick feedback that the changes will pass the build. When they merge them to master or to a version branch, then delete the branch, the multibranch job goes away.